# Running a for loop or .apply with a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I'm trying to run a for loop or .apply using lambdas for my pandas series. Here's the code:

```
df['sentiment_score'] = df.apply(lambda x: analyzer.polarity_scores(x['Filtered_text']), axis=1)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is **for each word** in `df['Filtered_text']`, apply the `analyzer.polartiy_scores(x['Filtered_text'])` through the column.

An example of what is stored in `df['Filtered_text']`:

```
[website, needs, convinient, terrible]
[filters, mobile, version, site]
```

So for every one of those words, I'd like it to be applied to the `analyzer.polarity_scores`

I've also tried this:

```
df['sentiment_score'] = df['Filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: analyzer.polarity_scores(x))
```

But I get this error:

> `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`

and this:

```
df['sentiment_score'] = df['Filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: [ft for ft in x: analyzer.polarity_scores(x)])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension to solve this:

```py
df['sentiment_score'] = df['Filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: [analyzer.polarity_scores(e) for e in x])
```

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was trying to achieve in my last example.